# How can we pass this params as json in postman

Tags: http, postman

[image]

am sending file and data to 3rd party API as form-data, have to send this as json form. How can we do ?

Comment: Use the "raw" option

Comment: yes tried but how can we pass the file ?

Comment: type your json into the box under the raw option